# Creating password protected zip file in java, during unzipping I am getting file not supported issue

Tags: java, android, security, zip, zip4j

I am able to create a zip file,my requirement is to protect it via password.For that I am using zip4j library.Please click on the further link for reference.[https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j]

Below is the code.

```
 public static void packZip(File output, List<File> sources) throws IOException {
System.out.println("Packaging to " + output.getName());
ZipOutputStream zipOut = initializeZipOutputStream(output, "password".toCharArray());
    

for (File source : sources) {
  if (source.isDirectory()) {
    zipDir(zipOut, "", source);
  } else {
    zipFile(zipOut, "", source);
  }
}
zipOut.flush();
zipOut.close();
System.out.println("Done");
```

}

```
private static void zipFile(ZipOutputStream zos, String path, File file) throws IOException {
if (!file.canRead()) {
  return;
}
ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
zipParameters.setAesKeyStrength(AesKeyStrength.KEY_STRENGTH_256);
zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(CompressionLevel.NORMAL);
zipParameters.setCompressionMethod(CompressionMethod.DEFLATE);
zipParameters.setFileNameInZip(buildPath(path,file.getName()));
zos.putNextEntry(zipParameters);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4092];
int byteCount = 0;
while ((byteCount = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  zos.write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
}
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file, "password".toCharArray());
zipFile.addFile(file, zipParameters);
//zipFile.createSplitZipFileFromFolder(file, zipParameters, true, 10485760);

fis.close();
zos.closeEntry();
```

}

```
private static ZipOutputStream initializeZipOutputStream(File outputZipFile, char[] password)
  throws IOException {

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputZipFile);

return new ZipOutputStream(fos, password);
```

}

```
private static void zipDir(ZipOutputStream zos, String path, File dir) throws IOException {
if (!dir.canRead()) {
  return;
}

File[] files = dir.listFiles();
path = buildPath(path, dir.getName());
for (File source : files) {
  if (source.isDirectory()) {
    zipDir(zos, path, source);
  } else {
    zipFile(zos, path, source);
  }
}
```

}

When I am using ZipFile class for password protection, I am not able to extract zip file, during extraction it changes from .zip to String format.
If I am using ZipOutputStream class for password protection, there is no change in file format during extraction but it is not asking the password as expected.
Any help is appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you mixing `ZipFlie` and `ZipOutputStream`? You need to use only one of those two. Refer to the examples on ziip4j readme.

Comment: I forgot to comment one of them, I tried both ways that is what I wanted to show you. First I tried via ZipOutPutStream-> zip is being created after downloading, when I am clicking to open, it is not asking for password as expected. ZipFile-> after downloading zip file if I tried to open file is changing from zip to String like "FileName.zip" then msg is displayed like Unsupported file format.